# createElement Unique Identifier

Tags: html, image, image-gallery, createelement

I am building a little gallery in Html and I am having some trouble with it. I have a `for` loop that creates an `img` every time it iterates. The problem is that once I have all the images produced and I try to pass a unique variable to my other function which displays the clicked image, there are no unique values I can pass.

I'm probably not explaining it well, but if you run it you'll see what I mean. Any help figuring out how I can obtain a unique identifier for each of the thumbnails would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script>
function loadPictures(){
    var a = new Array();

    a[0] = '1-m';
    a[1] = '2-m';
    a[2] = '3-m';

    document.getElementById('inWin').innerHTML='<img src="images/1-m.png" width="620px" height="auto" />';

    var ci = document.getElementById('pics');
    var newImg, divIdName;

    for(x=0; x<a.length; x++)
    {
        newImg = document.createElement('img');
        divIdName = 'portrait'+x;
        newImg.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        newImg.setAttribute('src', 'images/' + a[x] + 'thumb.png');
        newImg.setAttribute('onclick','changeContent(x);'); // for FF
        newImg.onclick = function() {changeContent(x);}; // for IE
        ci.appendChild(newImg); 
    }
}   
</script>

<script>
function changeContent(num){
    alert(num);
    var a = new Array();
    x=num;
    a[0] = '1-m';
    a[1] = '2-m';
    a[2] = '3-m';

    document.getElementById('inWin').innerHTML='<img src="images/'+ a[x] +'thumb.png" width="620px" height="auto" />';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPictures()">
<div id="inWin">
</div>
<div id="pics">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Since I am a newer member I can't upload the image, sorry.*

Comment: Add a link anyway. Somebody will help you insert it (as long as it's relevant) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the images already has a unique identifier, the ID attribute. You can work with this in different ways to get what you want. here's an idea of what it would look like:

```
<script>

var a = [ '1-m',
          '2-m',
          '3m'
        ];
function loadPictures(){

    document.getElementById('inWin').innerHTML='<img src="images/1-m.png" width="620px" height="auto" />';

    var ci = document.getElementById('pics');
    var newImg, divIdName;

    for(x=0; x<a.length; x++)
    {
        newImg = document.createElement('img');
        divIdName = 'portrait'+x;
        newImg.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        newImg.setAttribute('src', 'images/' + a[x] + 'thumb.png');
        if(document.addEventListener)
            newImg.addEventListener('click', changeContent, false);
        else if(document.attachEvent)
            newImg.attachEvent('onclick', changeContent);
        ci.appendChild(newImg); 
    }

}   

function changeContent(){

    x = this.id.split('portrait')[1];

    document.getElementById('inWin').innerHTML='<img src="images/'+ a[x] +'.png" width="620px" height="auto" />';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Spot on! That works perfect, I wouldn't even have thought to try it that way. Simple, concise, and as a bonus, it works! Thank you.